# Sending string value with link redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Given the following markup
When a user clicks the Register button, it is redirected to the Register Action in the Register controller. I also want to pass along the value from the EmailAddress input, so I can pre-populate the email address on the registration form.

Is there any way to do that with the new tag helpers in Asp.Net Core MVC 2 or do I have to do it in javascript? I know you can pass an id with asp-route-id but this isn't an id.

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only text-white" for="subscribe-email">Email address</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="email" id="subscribe-email" name="subscribe-email" placeholder="Your Email..">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-area="" asp-controller="Register" asp-action="Register">
         <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Register
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
         <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home
      </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  ATM there is no FORM tag so there is no way for this code to submit currently without javascript.  If you used a form tag, you could update the form url to whatever you wanted via javascript.  The advantage is that you don't have to redirect from the server.

Comment: You would need javascript to update the `href` attribute of the link based on the value in the textbox (or build a new url and use `location.href='..."` to do the redirect - and cancel the default redirect). But why not just use a `<form>` that makes a GET

Comment: That html is wrapped in a form, I just didn’t show it. Ok JavaScript it is

Comment: If its in a form, then javascript is not required. Just make the method a GET and use a submit button, not a link

Comment: @Stephen Mueke...Maybe I'm not being clear...this link routes to a different view in a different controller. I want to take the email address submitted here on the UnderConstruction page to the registration page to pre-populate the email address field on the registration page. I'm really not submitting a form from this page (I had it wrapped in a form, but then commented out the form part), just routing to a different view but want the email address to come along as a parameter. I just thought that maybe there was a way to do it with tag helpers I wasn't aware of. Passing as a query string?